# <non-existent> process is occupying port

Tags: cmd, pid, netstat

The thing I dont understand is in the red square. Translation is yellow.
How to free 80 port for apache if it is used by ghosty process?

[image]

Here is one more screenshot from TCPview showing  process occupying port 80, but i can niether end procces nor close connection..

[image]
Better pic: http://ssmaker.ru/09409ddc/

I've tried to moove my Apache to 8080 but now it complains about 443 port which also is used by  process.

Comment: this is definitely a fair question but you should revise your title (taskkill says the task doesnt exist but netstat does, etc)